# How can I see total deleted messages in discord.py

Tags: discord.io

I can delete a message with one or more limits;

```
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send("Deleted Message Count = BLA BLA")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

How can I see total deleten messages? (Not amount, For example, when I set the limit as 999, it can delete 256 messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextChannel.purge` returns a list of messages it deletes.

So all you have to do is:

```py
messages = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
total_deleted = len(messages)
await ctx.send(f"Delete {total_deleted} messages")
```

and instead of what you are doing, just do the following:

```py
messages = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
total_deleted = len(messages)
await ctx.send(f"Delete {total_deleted} messages", delete_after=2) # delete message after 2 seconds
```

alternatively, this can be done in the following way:

```py
messages = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
total_deleted = len(messages)
message = await ctx.send(f"Delete {total_deleted} messages")
await message.delete(delay=2)
```